# loading properties from s rest service call

Tags: spring-boot-configuration

In a spring boot application how can I load properties from a Rest service call in such a way that the properties can be overriden by command line arguments?

I am writing a spring boot application. The first thing it does is make a rest service call to obtain some data that configures the remainder of the application e.g. the last run date and time and list of stuff that needs to be processed.

Especially during development it is very useful to be able to override this configuration from the command line. I am capturing the command line overrides using @Value and have have some code that will return those in preference to the Rest configuration, but I wouldn't need this code if the Rest service was loaded as externalised configuration, say as a PropertySource.

Can anyone recommend an approach to this or even better point me to example code that does it already.

Note the Rest service is configured by application.yml.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You already mention the solution PropertySource. So go ahead and implement it as a PropertySource: http://zetcode.com/spring/propertysource/

Comment: As far as I can see PropertySource can only load properties from files so I don't see how it can be used to make a Rest call and then turn the results into properties in such a way that command line arguments can overwrite them.